# Changing width of an input whilst using a plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, plugins

I am using a plugin called [pickadate.js](http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/date/) and I want to be able to change the width of the input depending on what date i select for example.

[image]

I am trying to use [this](http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/date/#events) function 'onClose' to change the width of the input but having no success.

```
$('.datepicker').pickadate({
  formatSubmit: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
    onClose: function() {
      var dateFormat = $('.date').val();
      $('.dateSpan').text(dateFormat);
    },
});
```

This should have no spacing on the right but If I select a date say 10 May, 2016 it will not change the width of the input that it is in.

Comment: A [minimal, working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be very useful here. Create one using Codepen or jsFiddle :)

Comment: @KarlDawson I don't understand how to include plugins on jsFiddle or Codepen therefore it makes it difficult to replicate.

Comment: No worries, for Codepen press the cog on the JS pane and "Add External JavaScript" by pasting in the link to the [raw file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/amsul/pickadate.js/master/lib/picker.date.js) on Pickadate's github page. jsFiddle has something similar :)

Comment: There's also a Quick-Add dropdown for the jQuery library of your choice.